# mobile.loading takes too long to show

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-mobile, telerik, loader

We are building an app that makes some external calls by ajax POST and GET and during those calls we are trying to show the mobile.loading. The loaders we call from one page to another, inside "pagebeforecreate" are showing OK, as shown here:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforecreate', "#menu-principal", function(){     
setTimeout(function(){
    $.mobile.loading('show',
        {
            text: "Loading...",
            textVisible: true,
            theme: "b",
            textonly: true
        }
    );
},1);
```

});

Whenever we need to show a loader after a button click, the loader takes too long to appear and it loses all sense of showing it so the user knows he has to wait.

The button click calls a JS function that makes a POST and depending on the result of the POST, it may transition to another page or shows an alert. When the alert needs to be shown, the loader only appears in the same moment as the alert, when it should appear as soon as the user clicks the button and hide right before the alert.

**HTML with the button**

```
<div class="ui-field-contain">
  <span class="label">Matrícula com o dígito ou o CPF/CNPJ:</span>
  <input type="number" id="login_matricula" data-clear-btn="true">
</div>
<div class="ui-field-contain">
  <span class="label">Senha <small><a href="javascript:transitionPage('duvidas_senha.html', 'slideup', false, true)">Dúvidas sobre sua senha?</a></small></span>
  <input type="tel" id="login_senha" name="login_senha" style=" -webkit-text-security: disc;" data-clear-btn="true">
</div>
<div class="ui-field-contain">
    <a href="javascript:getLoginResult();"><button id="btn_envia_login" class="botao">Enviar</button></a>
</div>

<div class="banner">
    <div class="slider" id="sliderHome" role="toolbar"></div>
</div>
```

**JS with the function getLoginResult()**

```
function getLoginResult(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $.mobile.loading('show',
            {
                text: "Loading...",
                textVisible: true,
                theme: "b",
                textonly: true
            }
        );
    },0); 

    var url = "/mobile/service/logon";
    var matricula = $('#login_matricula').val();
    var senha = $('#login_senha').val();

    var data = {
        'username':matricula,
        'password':senha
    };

    var retorno = sendPostRequest(url, data);

    if(retorno['responseJSON']['status'] === true){
        var dadosAssociado = getDadosAssociado();
        localStorage.setItem("dadosAssociado", JSON.stringify(dadosAssociado));

        if(retorno['responseJSON']['aviso'] != null){
            // removes loading
            setTimeout(function(){         $.mobile.loading('hide');     },100);

            alert("Shows alert");
        }else{ 

        }
    }else{
        // removes loading
        setTimeout(function(){         $.mobile.loading('hide');     },100);
        alert("Fail to login");
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
It works in the browser but it doesn't work on the device.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
<a href="javascript:getLoginResult();"><button id="btn_envia_login" class="botao">Enviar</button></a>
```

to this:

```
<button id="btn_envia_login" class="botao">Enviar</button>
```

And bind your javascript code to the button click event:

```
$(document).on("click", "#btn_envia_login", function(){

    setTimeout(function(){
        $.mobile.loading('show',
            {
                text: "Loading...",
                textVisible: true,
                theme: "b",
                textonly: true
            }
        );
    },1);

    //etc
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1vmjc4bm/

---

**EDIT:**

Even better, put your HTML code inside a form, and bind your javascript code to the form submit event, like this:

HTML:

```
<form data-ajax="false" id="btn_envia_login">
    <!-- form content goes here -->
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
//Submit form
$(document).on("submit", "#btn_envia_login", function(e){
    //Prevent default action 
    e.preventDefault();

    //Display loader
    setTimeout(function(){
        $.mobile.loading('show',
            {
                text: "Loading...",
                textVisible: true,
                theme: "b",
                textonly: true
            }
        );
    },1); 

    //further handling
    //...
    //...
    //...

    //End with return false;
    return false;
});
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1vmjc4bm/1/